# How to identify the cause of 90% CPU percentages of app service plan in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to understand the reason of max CPU percentage/memory utilization of **app service plan** but unable to find any simple way in azure portal. In my app service plan there are 20 app services created and out of 20 only 2-3 app service I am using for user interface and others are using as web API or as background jobs (like webjobs). My app service plan is in isolated pricing tier and average memory and CPU utilization is good it's about 60% but when I check it for max utilization then I found it's being spike up to 90%. Is there anyway to find out the reason of reaching of app service plan utilization up to 90% ?

I am also using SQL database and database is in premium tier. Will DB utilization can impact app service plan utilization?

Please suggest.

Comment: did you try analyzing your CPU and diagnostics information with already available tools like similar to this? If yes, any specific findings you have fetched? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics

Comment: Thanks @Bhushan But in this way I'll have to go through each and every app service resources and will have to measure the CPU utilization/performance for specific timestamp right?

Comment: Thanks @Bhushan- I am able to see the cause using Diagnostics information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this by using the built-in feature of azure web app(see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics#interactive-interface)).

Nav to azure portal -> your azure web app -> in the left panel, click on `Diagnose and solve problems` -> click on `Proactive CPU Monitoring`, then you can see what is consuming high CPU resources.

Hope it helps.