# How to determine which App Service Slot consumes most CPU on an App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

We have an App Service Plan that is hosting lots of App Services. One of them is consuming lots of CPU resources. How can I determine within the Azure Portal which App Service Slot is responsible?

I've looked online and clicked around the Portal, but couldn't find a way of visualising CPU usage per App Service / App Service Slot.

Comment: Are those web apps connected to application insights?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify the cause of 90% CPU percentages of app service plan in azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544223/how-to-identify-the-cause-of-90-cpu-percentages-of-app-service-plan-in-azure)